# How Shiny reassign input after updateSelectInput call?

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following server code, which returns an error "attempt to select less than one element in get1index"

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$search, {
  ....
  enable("show_term")
  updateSelectInput(session, "show_term",
                    choices = list_of_terms, selected = list_of_terms[1])
  
  unique_words = unique(extended.dictionary[[which(list_of_terms == input$show_term)]][,c("word", "abbr")])
  
  ...
  })}
```

The error caused because `input$show_term` equal `""` and there is no such element in `list_of_term`. This means that `updateSelectInput` is not reassign the value for `input$show_term`.

However when I put the `unique_words` under `output$raw_dic = renderTable(...)` it works just fine.

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$search, {
  ....
  enable("show_term")
  updateSelectInput(session, "show_term",
                    choices = list_of_terms, selected = list_of_terms[1])

  output$raw_dictionary = renderTable(colnames = FALSE, striped = TRUE,
     {if (!(collected.data[[which(list_of_terms == input$show_term)]] %in%
                                                               c("No papers", "No matches"))){
      unique_words = unique(extended.dictionary[[which(list_of_terms == input$show_term)]][,c("word", "abbr")])
      collected.chuncks = collected.data[[which(list_of_terms == input$show_term)]]}})
  
  ...
  })}
```

So, in the second case in evaluates `which(list_of_terms == input$show_term)` and there is `input$show_term` is equal `list_of_terms[1]`.

Here I don't understand the logic behind the reassignment process. Can anyone explain it to me?

UPDATE: The full code of the shiny app is deposited at GitHub (problem part is in app.R lines 342-355): https://github.com/Dobrokhotov1989/Abbrevimate

Comment: Please provide a MRE, i.e. a complete, minimal running shiny app so that we can reproduce the behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: Have you made sure that there is actually something shown in `output$raw_dictionary`? Errors in `render` functions don't stop the complete app, it is just nothing shown in the respective output

Comment: @starja, I've added the link to the GitHub repo with full code.  As for `output$raw_dictionaty`, it works just fine either with `unique_words = ...` or without.  Actually, the `unique_words` does not add anything to the `output$raw_dictionary`. Surprisingly for me, `which(list_of_terms == input$show_term)` somehow differently evaluated when it is outside of `output$raw_dictionary` leading to the mentioned error.